# How to automatic update a specific row from an existing user logged in

Tags: php, mysql

For example when the user is login, after login I want to automatic update a specific row from this actual user. How can I do for it?
Well when the user is login I want to update is row points, I want to add some points to it, for example 5 points.
I have try a few examples but it just add other row but not for this specific user

```html
<?php
   session_start();
   include_once 'dbconnect.php';

   if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
   header("Location: index.php");
   }

   $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
   $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
   // Retrieve data from database 
   $sql="SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY user_points DESC LIMIT 10";
   $result=mysql_query($sql);
   $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_points`) VALUES ('5');");
   // Start looping rows in mysql database.


  print "Top 10 Users! ";
  while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $rows['user_name'] . " * " . $rows['user_points'] . " * ";

    // close while loop 
  }

  // close MySQL connection 
  mysql_close();


  $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  $sec = "30";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<div id="header">
 <div id="left">
    <label>Bitcoin Rotator</label>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
     <div id="content">
         hi' <?php echo $userRow['user_name']; ?>&nbsp;<a href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a>
  Welcome Back Your Points <?php echo $userRow['user_points']; ?>
<a href="http://bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt/"> Bitcoin Rotator</a><br /><br />
<style> 
#main {
    width: 70px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}

#main div {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}
</style>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="body">
 <a href="http://bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt/faucet/" style="color: rgb(0,255,0)"><font color="FF00CC"; style="color: rgb(0,255,0)" >Click Here</font><font color="FF00CC"> to go on our faucet</font></a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="http://bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt/login-registration/get all points.php/" style="color: rgb(0,255,0)"><font color="FF00CC"; style="color: rgb(0,255,0)" >Click Here</font><font color="FF00CC"> to see the top 10 users!</font></a>

<br>
<br>
<a href="http://bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt/login-registration/urls_rotator.php/" style="color: rgb(0,255,0)"><font color="FF00CC"; style="color: rgb(0,255,0)" >Make Your Rotator </font><font color="FF00CC">Click Here To Start!</font></a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="http://bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt/login-registration/geturlonarray.php/" style="color: rgb(0,255,0)"><font color="FF00CC"; style="color: rgb(0,255,0)" >All The Rotators From Our Website </font><font color="FF00CC">Click Here To Start!</font></a>
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;"></div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;"></div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;"></div>
</div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i liked to update to the current users the row user_points i have try like this but is not update is do a new one $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_points`) VALUES ('5');");

Comment: You have a security problem: SQL-Injection. Never construct SQL-Statements like this:
... WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']

Comment: You can thank the people that helped you by upvoting their answer.

Answer (score 0):

The query you need is

```
$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']);
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET user_points = user_points + 5 WHERE user_id = " . $user_id);
```

Please don't use `mysql_` library because it was deprecated (use `mysqli_` instead)

Comment: @HelderDaSilveiraVentura DO NOT USE `mysql_query`. Its deprecated. Use the mysqli extention

Comment: it is possible to me to add 0.005 in place of the 5 because i have try and its not add nothing

Comment: @HelderDaSilveiraVentura Not if the type of `user_points` is `INT` or `BIGINT`, you need to change the type of the field to `DECIMAL(5,3)` in order for this to work ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html))

Comment: tanks for the replay i have try like this after to change the type of field to decimal the numbers on menu its become 0.000 but wen it should update the numbers nothing is add $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET points=`points`+0,1 WHERE user_id='".$_SESSION['user']."'");

Comment: Please rewrite the solution in a way that prevents SQL-Injections.

Comment: tanks for all the help well after to have change to decimal i have set the field type top decimal and value to (8,8) its become what i wanted but now  its not update the values $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']);
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET user_points = user_points +0.5 WHERE user_id = " . $_SESSION['user']);

Comment: @HelderDaSilveiraVentura Try escape the value, change `0.5` to `'0.5'`, If id doesn't work, please open a new question for this issue

Comment: tanks for the help now its work but web its come on 0,99999999 its stuck on that number it s not aumentate more than that

Comment: @HelderDaSilveiraVentura Please open a new question, since this (the decimal issue) is way off-topic of the original question

Answer (score 0):

you try to INSERT the value 5 every time the user logged on 
what you want is UPDATE the content of row points
u can do this by this command sql

```
"UPDATE `users` SET points=`points`+5 WHERE user_id='".$_SESSION['user']."'"
```

Comment: tanks for the help i have try this last one and nothing happened

Comment: "UPDATE `users` SET user_points=`user_points`+5 WHERE user_id='".$_SESSION['user']."'"

Comment: Please rewrite the solution in a way that prevents SQL-Injections.